# Error codes support for our Onion Architecture

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

We are planning to implement our own errorcodes in our asp.net MVC application.

We would like to bundle together the similar errors . Between certain numbers, within the interval described by them we will have similar errors/notifications.

looking for something similar this

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681381(VS.85).aspx

What is the best way of doing it ? is there any patters or industry standards that we need to follow ?

Am actually against about this idea but it is our requirement!

Comment: Are the error codes important to the web application in any way, or are they strictly a "backend" concern?  (How will the errors be used?)

Comment: It is just for the back and for an easy reference back

Comment: In that case, (just to share a thought process regarding Onion Architecture) I believe you can take the "Onion Architecture" requirement out of the picture.  Because the MVC application doesn't care about the error codes, you don't have anything related to error codes in your Core, and therefor your infrastructure is not required to provide any special implementation to handle them.

Answer (score 0):

Because your MVC application doesn't care about what error codes are produced, where they go, how they're processed...etc., you don't need to provide any specific implementation for handling errors in regards to the application.  It's purely up to how you feel like keeping records.

This is something I am currently doing for this same scenario:

My Core service definition:

```
public interface IExceptionService
{
     void Handle(Exception exception);
}
```

My Infrastructure service implementation:

```
public sealed class ExceptionService : IExceptionService
{
    public void Handle(Exception exception)
    {
         /* What you do with errors is up to you. */
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
private readonly IExceptionService _exceptionService;  // Get's set via IoC.
```

...

```
try
{
    /* Something that may throw an Exception goes here. */
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    _exceptionService.Handle(ex);
}
```